# Run Jetpack compose tests with AndroidJunit4 and no device

Tags: android, android-testing, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to android testing and no idea whether this can happen or not.
Is it possible to run **Jetpack compose** unit tests using `androidx.test.ext` **AndroidJunit4** runner?

So we don't need to run `instrumentation` tests and use a device.

Here's what I've tried:

`app/src/test/`:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleUnitTest {

    @get:Rule
    val activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()
    // createComposeRule() if you don't need access to the activityTestRule

    @Test
    fun greeting_showsGreetingText() {
        // Start the app
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            analyzerTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Hello Android!").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```

Running the test I get the following error:

```
No tests found for given includes: [greeting_showsGreetingText]
```

Comment: I believe you'd still need to use Robolectric if you want to use ActivityScenarioRule in unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

As of **beta09**, compose tests are *supposed* to be able to work with Robolectric now, with some limitations.
See [Compose release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.0.0-beta09) for reference.

Admissibly, I haven't been able to get it to work, but I haven't tried very hard (yet.) :)

Answer (score 1):

Compose tests are still instrumentation tests, can't be run without a physical device or emulator

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the Robolectric version you're using supports your `targetSdk`.

We were getting this error for new modules but not existing ones. It turns out the existing ones had `robolectric.properties` files specifying an older SDK version, but the new one defaulted to the current `targetSdk`.

Updating the robolectric version solved the problem.